# Exception Copying Stream from Payload

Tags: java, android, stream, inputstream, google-nearby

Im having a hard time fixing this stuffs.The setup is, i implemented the onPreviewFrame method of Camera.PreviewCallback object to get the frame by frame bytes of data to be send to the connected device.

```
  Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback= new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: BYTE SIZE: "+bytes.toString() );
        framesCallback.getCurrentData(bytes);
    }
};
```

The Callback is **framesCallback.getCurrentData(bytes);** . I implemented the callback inside the CameraActivity and here's the code:

```
/**
 * INITIALIZE THE REALTIME CALLBACK FOR GETTING RAW DATA OF SURFACE(IMAGE) TO BE SEND AS PAYLOAD
 */
private void initFramesToBeSendCallback() {
    surfaceHolder.setFramesToBeRetrieveListener(new CustomSurfaceHolder.OnCaptureFramesToBeSendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void getCurrentData(byte[] bytes) {
            if (isRecording) {
                Log.e(TAG, "initFramesToBeSendCallback RECORDING, will send data!");
                is= new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                sendFramesOfImages(is);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "initFramesToBeSendCallback NOT RECORDING");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Since it updates and sends every frame bytes, i use the method:

```
 is= new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            sendFramesOfImages(is);
```

to Read every bytes and save it in InputStream. and the method **sendFramesOfImages(is);**, sends realtime frame data. Here's is the Google Nearby Connections sending stream data payload, parameter is my created inputstream :

```
 private void sendFramesOfImages(InputStream is) {
    Nearby.Connections.sendPayload(client, SERVICE_ID, Payload.fromStream(is))
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResult: STREAM DATA SUCCESS");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

when the Button that triggers the sending of data clicked. It display error log

```
02-28 04:22:53.015 12814-12898/shaveyourneck.syn.app.com.shaveyourneck W/NearbyConnections: Unable to deliver status for Payload -5402869508027937544
                                                                                        java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:542)
                                                                                            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
                                                                                            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:191)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcom.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcom.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcon.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                         Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:223)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:537)
                                                                                            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
                                                                                            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:191) 
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcom.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcom.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcon.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

And i cant send the data needed. Any help in this please? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in your sendPayload call. It should be `sendPayload(GoogleApiClient, remoteEndpointId, Payload)`, but you're passing in SERVICE_ID as the remoteEndpointId.

Past that, you're making a new stream for every frame of data. I'd recommend making a single stream to continuously pump data through. It'll be more efficient.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] payloadPipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

// Send the remote side one half of the payload pipe.
Nearby.getConnectionsClient(context).sendPayload(endpointId, Payload.fromStream(payloadPipe[0]));

// Use the other half of the payload pipe to pump data through.
surfaceHolder.setFramesToBeRetrieveListener(new CustomSurfaceHolder.OnCaptureFramesToBeSendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void getCurrentData(byte[] bytes) {
            if (isRecording) {
                payloadPipe[1].write(bytes);
            }
        }
    });
```